# All li tag under first ul tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all a tags with href attrs in all li tags under first ul tag. The below code scrape all all a tags under all li tags in all ul tags. (I want only under the first ul tag). You can see the website.
https://www.mindtools.com/pages/main/newMN_CDV.htm
my code is:

```
for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'collection test_further_resource'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        print(litag.find("a")["href"])
```

Please see the website. Please go to "Browse tools by Category" and "Thinking about Career direction". I want to scrape the href for this category which are 13.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` will return the first tag it finds that matches, as opposed to `.find_all()` which will return a list of all the matches.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mindtools.com/pages/main/newMN_CDV.htm'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


ultag = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'collection test_further_resource'})
for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
    print(litag.find("a")["href"])
```

**Output:**

```
/pages/article/managing-career.htm
/pages/article/newCDV_97.htm
/pages/article/career-strategy.htm
/pages/article/personal-ansoff-matrix.htm
/pages/article/career-opportunities.htm
/pages/article/managing-yourself.htm
/pages/article/newCDV_99.htm
/pages/article/newCDV_89.htm
/pages/article/rebooting-your-career.htm
/pages/article/newCDV_98.htm
/pages/article/locus-of-control.htm
/pages/article/newCDV_90.htm
/pages/article/seat-on-the-board.htm
```

Comment: I already did that but it gave me the error "NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all"

Comment: Sure you implemented it correctly? Works fine for me. See code above.

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requestsurl = "https://www.mindtools.com/pages/main/newMN_CDV.htm"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'collection test_further_resource'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        link =  litag.find("a")["href"]

Comment: like I said, you need to use `.find()`, not `find_all()`. Just for future reference, don't post that block of code in the comments (unless it's a one-liner), go back and add it to your original post.

Comment: chitown88 thank you for the answer. Yes, it is now working. As I commented earlier I already tried that but that was giving me the Nagivablestring error. But when I copied your code and run it in different cell it worked. I don't know why it did'nt worked in other cells. strange. thank you very much. so nice of you.

Comment: My guess is you pulled out the text or attribute (which gets stored as a string), then you were trying to `.find_all()` on that string on the next line, as opposed to .`find_all()` on the beautifulsoup object. Just a guess.